# Can't get a specific mesh to render (though everything else renders fine)

Tags: rendering, mesh

Trying to make my first 3d animation. Spent the past hour looking through fixes for similar issues but nothing has worked for me so far. This is really weird because I don't think the object is entirely invisible. Rather than describing, I'll share screenshots of 1. solid mode viewport, 2. material preview mode viewport, 3. rendered frame (note the eery black outline of meshes face, I'm certain it is the face because when I move mesh that black outline moves in render). What's weird is, I initially had this working perfectly, but after changing the keyframes for my animation (spacing them out), adding a floor and background it just stopped showing the humanoid mesh. I'm also unsure why it's completely black but that is not my primary concern right now. Things I've tried: hiding and unhiding in viewport, disabling and enabling in rendering, clear all resrict render.[image: Img 1] [image][image]

Blend file (sorry, blend-exchange was taking forever so I uploaded to google drive):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_oInTQqhWHFPOl7p9XTM6LVqx6N-9wEc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/186170/edit) and [share a .blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) if you want to get any meaningful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your object have Alpha is 0, you need to go to select your object, then go to the Material properties > Alpha, and change this to 1

[image]